# Laravel / Eloquent - Multiple Many to Many Relationships Using One Reference Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a table that looks lie:

[image]

The table serves as a reference table between two tables.  The kicker is that the second table this reference table serves depends on the value of `member_type`.

There are three tables being connected using the above table: `incidents`, `user_member_incidents`, and `server_member_incidents`.  The `member_id` column in the reference table references either the `user_member_incidents` table or the `server_member_incidents` table.  This is determined by the value of the `member_type` column.

How would I reflect this relationship using a `belongsToMany` method in Eloquent?

Comment: Have you considered [many to many polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have `Incident`, `UserMember`, and `ServerMember` models, you can define the following relationships:

```php
class Incident extends Model
{
    public function userMember()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            UserMember::class, 
            'your_pivot_table_name', 
            'incident_id', 
            'member_id'
        )->wherePivot('member_type', 1);
    }

    public function serverMember()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            ServerMember::class, 
            'your_pivot_table_name', 
            'incident_id', 
            'member_id'
        )->wherePivot('member_type', 2);
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question.